# How to store Bikram Samwat date format?

Tags: php, mysql

i need to insert B.S.(Bikram Samwat) date inside MySQL using php..... The code store date but failed to store date in which days r 31 or 32. As in bikram samwat days in some months r 32 n 31 ... Failed to get the solution.... Hope Someone solve it here....

`nepali_calendar.php` is:

```
<?php

class Nepali_Calendar
{
    private $bs = array(0 => array(2000, 30, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 30, 29, 31), 1 => array(2001, 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 31, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30), 2 => array(2002, 31, 31, 32, 32, 31, 30, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30), 3 => array(2003, 31, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 29, 30, 31), 4 => array(2004, 30, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 30, 29, 31), 5 => array(2005, 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 31, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30), 6 => array(2006, 31, 31, 32, 32, 31, 30, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30), 7 => array(2007, 31, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 29, 30, 31), 8 => array(2008, 31, 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 29, 30, 30, 29, 29, 31), 9 => array(2009, 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 31, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30), 10 => array(2010, 31, 31, 32, 32, 31, 30, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30), 11 => array(2011, 31, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 29, 30, 31), 12 => array(2012, 31, 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 29, 30, 30, 29, 30, 30), 13 => array(2013, 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 31, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30), 14 => array(2014, 31, 31, 32, 32, 31, 30, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30), 15 => array(2015, 31, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 29, 30, 31), 16 => array(2016, 31, 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 29, 30, 30, 29, 30, 30), 17 => array(2017, 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 31, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30), 18 => array(2018, 31, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30), 19 => array(2019, 31, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 30, 29, 31), 20 => array(2020, 31, 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30), 21 => array(2021, 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 31, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30), 22 => array(2022, 31, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 29, 30, 30), 23 => array(2023, 31, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 30, 29, 31), 24 => array(2024, 31, 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30), 25 => array(2025, 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 31, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30), 26 => array(2026, 31, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 29, 30, 31), 27 => array(2027, 30, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 30, 29, 31), 28 => array(2028, 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 31, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30), 29 => array(2029, 31, 31, 32, 31, 32, 30, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30), 30 => array(2030, 31, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 29, 30, 31), 31 => array(2031, 30, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 30, 29, 31), 32 => array(2032, 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 31, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30), 33 => array(2033, 31, 31, 32, 32, 31, 30, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30), 34 => array(2034, 31, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 29, 30, 31), 35 => array(2035, 30, 32, 31, 32, 31, 31, 29, 30, 30, 29, 29, 31), 36 => array(2036, 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 31, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30), 37 => array(2037, 31, 31, 32, 32, 31, 30, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30), 38 => array(2038, 31, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 29, 30, 31), 39 => array(2039, 31, 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 29, 30, 30, 29, 30, 30), 40 => array(2040, 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 31, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30), 41 => array(2041, 31, 31, 32, 32, 31, 30, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30), 42 => array(2042, 31, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 29, 30, 31), 43 => array(2043, 31, 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 29, 30, 30, 29, 30, 30), 44 => array(2044, 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 31, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30), 45 => array(2045, 31, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30), 46 => array(2046, 31, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 29, 30, 31), 47 => array(2047, 31, 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30), 48 => array(2048, 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 31, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30), 49 => array(2049, 31, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 29, 30, 30), 50 => array(2050, 31, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 30, 29, 31), 51 => array(2051, 31, 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30), 52 => array(2052, 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 31, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30), 53 => array(2053, 31, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 29, 30, 30), 54 => array(2054, 31, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 30, 29, 31), 55 => array(2055, 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 31, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30), 56 => array(2056, 31, 31, 32, 31, 32, 30, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30), 57 => array(2057, 31, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 29, 30, 31), 58 => array(2058, 30, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 30, 29, 31), 59 => array(2059, 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 31, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30), 60 => array(2060, 31, 31, 32, 32, 31, 30, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30), 61 => array(2061, 31, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 29, 30, 31), 62 => array(2062, 30, 32, 31, 32, 31, 31, 29, 30, 29, 30, 29, 31), 63 => array(2063, 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 31, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30), 64 => array(2064, 31, 31, 32, 32, 31, 30, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30), 65 => array(2065, 31, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 29, 30, 31), 66 => array(2066, 31, 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 29, 30, 30, 29, 29, 31), 67 => array(2067, 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 31, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30), 68 => array(2068, 31, 31, 32, 32, 31, 30, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30), 69 => array(2069, 31, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 29, 30, 31), 70 => array(2070, 31, 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 29, 30, 30, 29, 30, 30), 71 => array(2071, 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 31, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30), 72 => array(2072, 31, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30), 73 => array(2073, 31, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 29, 30, 31), 74 => array(2074, 31, 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30), 75 => array(2075, 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 31, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30), 76 => array(2076, 31, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 29, 30, 30), 77 => array(2077, 31, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 30, 29, 31), 78 => array(2078, 31, 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30), 79 => array(2079, 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 31, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30), 80 => array(2080, 31, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 29, 30, 30), 81 => array(2081, 31, 31, 32, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 30, 30, 30), 82 => array(2082, 30, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 30, 30, 30), 83 => array(2083, 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 30, 30, 30), 84 => array(2084, 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 30, 30, 30), 85 => array(2085, 31, 32, 31, 32, 30, 31, 30, 30, 29, 30, 30, 30), 86 => array(2086, 30, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 30, 30, 30), 87 => array(2087, 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 31, 30, 30, 29, 30, 30, 30), 88 => array(2088, 30, 31, 32, 32, 30, 31, 30, 30, 29, 30, 30, 30), 89 => array(2089, 30, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 30, 30, 30), 90 => array(2090, 30, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 30, 30, 30));

    //private $nep_date = array('year'=>'', 'month'=>'', 'date'=>'',           'day'=>'','nmonth'=>'','num_day'=>'');
    private $eng_date = array('year' => '', 'month' => '', 'date' => '', 'day' => '', 'emonth' => '', 'num_day' => '');
    public $debug_info = "";


    /**
     * Calculates wheather english year is leap year or not
     *
     * @param integer $year
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function is_leap_year($year)
    {
        $a = $year;
        if ($a % 100 == 0) {
            if ($a % 400 == 0) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }

        } else {
            if ($a % 4 == 0) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    private function get_nepali_month($m)
    {
        $n_month = false;

        switch ($m) {
            case 1:
                $n_month = "Baishakh";
                break;

                $n_month = "Jestha";
                break;

            case 3:
                $n_month = "Ashad";
                break;

            case 4:
                $n_month = "Shrawan";
                break;

            case 5:
                $n_month = "Bhadra";
                break;

            case 6:
                $n_month = "Ashwin";
                break;

            case 7:
                $n_month = "Kartik";
                break;

            case 8:
                $n_month = "Mangshir";
                break;

            case 9:
                $n_month = "Poush";
                break;

            case 10:
                $n_month = "Magh";
                break;

            case 11:
                $n_month = "Falgun";
                break;

            case 12:
                $n_month = "Chaitra";
                break;
        }
        return $n_month;
    }

    private function get_english_month($m)
    {
        $eMonth = false;
        switch ($m) {
            case 1:
                $eMonth = "January";
                break;
            case 2:
                $eMonth = "February";
                break;
            case 3:
                $eMonth = "March";
                break;
            case 4:
                $eMonth = "April";
                break;
            case 5:
                $eMonth = "May";
                break;
            case 6:
                $eMonth = "June";
                break;
            case 7:
                $eMonth = "July";
                break;
            case 8:
                $eMonth = "August";
                break;
            case 9:
                $eMonth = "September";
                break;
            case 10:
                $eMonth = "October";
                break;
            case 11:
                $eMonth = "November";
                break;
            case 12:
                $eMonth = "December";
        }
        return $eMonth;
    }

    private function get_day_of_week($day)
    {
        switch ($day) {
            case 1:
                $day = "Sunday";
                break;

            case 2:
                $day = "Monday";
                break;

            case 3:
                $day = "Tuesday";
                break;

            case 4:
                $day = "Wednesday";
                break;

            case 5:
                $day = "Thursday";
                break;

            case 6:
                $day = "Friday";
                break;

            case 7:
                $day = "Saturday";
                break;
        }
        return $day;
    }


    public function is_range_eng($yy, $mm, $dd)
    {
        if ($yy < 1944 || $yy > 2033) {
            $this->debug_info = "Supported only between 1944-2033";
            return false;
        }

        if ($mm < 1 || $mm > 12) {
            $this->debug_info = "Error! value 1-12 only";
            return false;
        }

        if ($dd < 1 || $dd > 31) {
            $this->debug_info = "Error! value 1-31 only";
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    public function is_range_nep($yy, $mm, $dd)
    {
        if ($yy < 2000 || $yy > 2089) {
            $this->debug_info = "Supported only between 2000-2089";
            return false;
        }

        if ($mm < 1 || $mm > 12) {
            $this->debug_info = "Error! value 1-12 only";
            return false;
        }

        if ($dd < 1 || $dd > 32) {
            $this->debug_info = "Error! value 1-31 only";
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }


    /**
     * currently can only calculate the date between AD 1944-2033...
     *
     * @param unknown_type $yy
     * @param unknown_type $mm
     * @param unknown_type $dd
     * @return unknown
     */

    public function eng_to_nep($yy, $mm, $dd)
    {
        if ($this->is_range_eng($yy, $mm, $dd) == false) {
            return false;
        } else {

            // english month data.
            $month  = array(
                31,
                28,
                31,
                30,
                31,
                30,
                31,
                31,
                30,
                31,
                30,
                31
            );
            $lmonth = array(
                31,
                29,
                31,
                30,
                31,
                30,
                31,
                31,
                30,
                31,
                30,
                31
            );

            $def_eyy     = 1944; //spear head english date...
            $def_nyy     = 2000;
            $def_nmm     = 9;
            $def_ndd     = 17 - 1; //spear head nepali date...
            $total_eDays = 0;
            $total_nDays = 0;
            $a           = 0;
            $day         = 7 - 1; //all the initializations...
            $m           = 0;
            $y           = 0;
            $i           = 0;
            $j           = 0;
            $numDay      = 0;

            // count total no. of days in-terms of year
            for ($i = 0; $i < ($yy - $def_eyy); $i++) { //total days for month calculation...(english)
                if ($this->is_leap_year($def_eyy + $i) == 1)
                    for ($j = 0; $j < 12; $j++)
                        $total_eDays += $lmonth[$j];
                else
                    for ($j = 0; $j < 12; $j++)
                        $total_eDays += $month[$j];
            }

            // count total no. of days in-terms of month
            for ($i = 0; $i < ($mm - 1); $i++) {
                if ($this->is_leap_year($yy) == 1)
                    $total_eDays += $lmonth[$i];
                else
                    $total_eDays += $month[$i];
            }

            // count total no. of days in-terms of date
            $total_eDays += $dd;


            $i           = 0;
            $j           = $def_nmm;
            $total_nDays = $def_ndd;
            $m           = $def_nmm;
            $y           = $def_nyy;

            // count nepali date from array
            while ($total_eDays != 0) {
                $a = $this->bs[$i][$j];
                $total_nDays++; //count the days
                $day++; //count the days interms of 7 days
                if ($total_nDays > $a) {
                    $m++;
                    $total_nDays = 1;
                    $j++;
                }
                if ($day > 7)
                    $day = 1;
                if ($m > 12) {
                    $y++;
                    $m = 1;
                }
                if ($j > 12) {
                    $j = 1;
                    $i++;
                }
                $total_eDays--;
            }

            $numDay = $day;

            $this->nep_date[0] = $y;
            $this->nep_date[1] = $m;
            $this->nep_date[2] = $total_nDays;
            //$this->nep_date["day"] = $this->get_day_of_week($day);
            //$this->nep_date["month_name"] = $this->get_nepali_month($m);
            //$this->nep_date["num_day"] = $numDay;
            return $this->nep_date;
        }
    }


    /**
     * currently can only calculate the date between BS 2000-2089
     *
     * @param unknown_type $yy
     * @param unknown_type $mm
     * @param unknown_type $dd
     * @return unknown
     */
    private function n_to_e($yy, $mm, $dd)
    {

        $def_eyy     = 1943;
        $def_emm     = 4;
        $def_edd     = 14 - 1; // init english date.
        $def_nyy     = 2000;
        $def_nmm     = 1;
        $def_ndd     = 1; // equivalent nepali date.
        $total_eDays = 0;
        $total_nDays = 0;
        $a           = 0;
        $day         = 4 - 1; // initializations...
        $m           = 0;
        $y           = 0;
        $i           = 0;
        $k           = 0;
        $numDay      = 0;

        $month  = array(
            0,
            31,
            28,
            31,
            30,
            31,
            30,
            31,
            31,
            30,
            31,
            30,
            31
        );
        $lmonth = array(
            0,
            31,
            29,
            31,
            30,
            31,
            30,
            31,
            31,
            30,
            31,
            30,
            31
        );

        if ($this->is_range_nep($yy, $mm, $dd) === false) {
            return false;

        } else {

            // count total days in-terms of year
            for ($i = 0; $i < ($yy - $def_nyy); $i++) {
                for ($j = 1; $j <= 12; $j++) {
                    $total_nDays += $this->bs[$k][$j];
                }
                $k++;
            }

            // count total days in-terms of month
            for ($j = 1; $j < $mm; $j++) {
                $total_nDays += $this->bs[$k][$j];
            }

            // count total days in-terms of dat
            $total_nDays += $dd;

            //calculation of equivalent english date...
            $total_eDays = $def_edd;
            $m           = $def_emm;
            $y           = $def_eyy;
            while ($total_nDays != 0) {
                if ($this->is_leap_year($y)) {
                    $a = $lmonth[$m];
                } else {
                    $a = $month[$m];
                }
                $total_eDays++;
                $day++;
                if ($total_eDays > $a) {
                    $m++;
                    $total_eDays = 1;
                    if ($m > 12) {
                        $y++;
                        $m = 1;
                    }
                }
                if ($day > 7)
                    $day = 1;
                $total_nDays--;
            }
            $numDay = $day;

            $this->eng_date["year"]       = $y;
            $this->eng_date["month"]      = $m;
            $this->eng_date["date"]       = $total_eDays;
            $this->eng_date["day"]        = $this->get_day_of_week($day);
            $this->eng_date["month_name"] = $this->get_english_month($m);
            $this->eng_date["num_day"]    = $numDay;

            return $this->eng_date;

        }
    }
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////
    public function nep_to_eng($yy, $mm, $dd)
    {
        $arr      = $this->n_to_e($yy, $mm, $dd);
        $et_year  = $arr['year'];
        $et_month = $arr['month'];
        $et_date  = $arr['date'];
        $new_nep  = $this->eng_to_nep($et_year, $et_month, $et_date);
        //showpre($new_nep,'new_nep');
        //showpre($yy.' '.$mm.' '.$dd,'original');
        //showpre($arr,'eng');
        //showpre($new_nep,'new nep');
        if ($new_nep['year'] == $yy && $new_nep['month'] == $mm && $new_nep['date'] == $dd) {
            return $arr;
        } else {
            $err_arr['error']         = 1;
            $err_arr['error_message'] = 'Invalid Date';
            return $err_arr;
        }
    }

}

?>
```

**today.php**

```
<?php
//Core file
error_reporting(0);
$dateType     = 'en';
$dateFormat   = $_GET['dateFormat'];
$dateLanguage = $_GET['dateLanguage'];
$showTime     = ($_GET['showTime'] == 'true') ? true : false;
$militaryTime = ($_GET['militaryTime'] == 'true') ? true : false;
//
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Katmandu');
include('nepali_calendar.php');
$cal      = new Nepali_Calendar();
$eflag    = false;
//
$date_arr = explode('-', date('Y-m-d'));
if (!$cal->is_range_eng($date_arr[0], $date_arr[1], $date_arr[2]) && !$eflag) {
    $ret_op['error']         = 1;
    $ret_op['error_message'] = 'Date out of range';
    $eflag                   = true;
}

if (!$eflag) {
    $newd = $cal->eng_to_nep($date_arr[0], $date_arr[1], $date_arr[2]);

    if ($dateLanguage == 'np') {
        $newd = convertToNepali($newd);
    }
    $outpur_arr = $newd;
    if ($showTime == true) {
        if ($militaryTime == true)
            $current_time = date('H-i-s');
        else
            $current_time = date('h-i-s');
        list($time_hour, $time_minute, $time_second) = explode('-', $current_time);
        $outpur_arr['time_hour']   = $time_hour;
        $outpur_arr['time_minute'] = $time_minute;
        $outpur_arr['time_second'] = $time_second;
    }
} else {
    $outpur_arr = $ret_op;
}
$year = '';
foreach ($outpur_arr as $val) {
    //echo $val ; // it will show value 
    $valArr = explode("-", $val); // explode will break string from - and convert it into array                           // so $valArr[0] will be test and $valArr[1] will be rate 
    $year   = $valArr[0];
    $month  = $valArr[1];
    $day    = $valArr[2];
    echo $year;
    echo "/";
    echo $month;
    echo $day;
}
//$json_encoded=$outpur_arr;
//$callback=$_GET['callback'];
//$op=$callback.'('.$outpur_arr.')';
?>
```

I only want to insert the value inside MySQL of the date displays using these code.

But I only get 0000-00-00 as a result.

Comment: There's a missing `close comment` in there somewhere

Comment: ... I have to sort this indentation out.

Comment: @hek2mgl and Orangepill see this http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22233/179506

Comment: I don't fully understand the code above, nor do I know how the Nepali calendar works, but I would consider storing the western date using a standard DATETIME field, and converting it from/to the local format at input and output time. That gives you all the convenient filtering and sorting options of a native DATETIME field

Comment: I think you might be trying to reinvent the wheel.  You should look into MySQL's localization capabilities.  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/locale-support.html

Comment: it displays the date as 2070/4/31/ and i just want to insert it in mysql date column having field value 'date'..... when i changed it into 'varchar' it stores it but i failed to insert it in date format.... plz help me....

Comment: some month in bikram sambat has 32 days also... and some has 28 too..... but mysql doesn't store it.

Comment: the problem I found in storing date having days 31 and 32 ..... can ne1 help me ....plz

Answer (score 2):

MySQL has no way of storing a Bikram Samwat date natively. You basically have two options:

The first option is to **not** store it in BS format. Store in regular Gregorian format and do the conversion when you want to display it to the user. This will also allow you to make use of the PHP [DateTime](http://php.net/datetime) object to manipulate things as well as the native MySQL date functions, so this is definitely preferred.

I came across the code you pasted above (and formatted correctly, so I don't know where you got all those crazy indentations from) from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nepalidateconve/), so looking at the example, just do:

```
$cal = new Nepali_Calendar();
$eng_date = $cal->nep_to_eng(2070,04,31); // Produces 2013-08-15
```

Then just insert that normally into your MySQL table using `Date` type. If you want to query using a BS date, convert it to normal date first before you query the DB. Basically the only time it will be converted to the BS format is when it is outputted to the user or when it is provided by a user.

The second way (which I wouldn't recommend) is storing it as `VARCHAR(10)` in the DB. The major problem with doing it this way is you lose all functionality of having a proper `Date` type, such as adding and subtracting days, and some comparisons may not work. There's also nothing that would prevent you from entering a date as "bananas" since it's a valid string for `VARCHAR(10)`.

So basically, don't store in BS format.